# How to randomize PDF page order using pdftools

Tags: r, pdf, pdftools

I am trying to randomize the page order of a 382-page PDF. I've read that the pdftools package may be the way to go, but I'm not sure if it's able to randomize the PDF order. I was thinking of using pdf_subset to split the existing PDF into two and then using pdf_combine to stick them back together, but I realize that this would just bind them one after the other and not actually mix up the pages. I've also tried something similar in Automator on my Mac (didn't work) but I was curious if there was a way to do this in R.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please have a look at functions `split_pdf` and `select_pages` from `staplr` package

Comment: select_pages(sample(1:length(pages)) gives a random permutation of the pages of a pdf doc just as sample(1:5) gives a random permutation of 1:5.